# Get text properties from PDF file

Tags: perl, pdf

How can I get text properties using [`PDF::API2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2) or [`CAM::PDF`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF)? I need font size and style info.

Something like (from `CAM::PDF`)

```
$pdf->getPageContent(1);
```

but with text info in it.

Answer (score 1):

These modules you can acheive the extract text from pdf

- [`PDF::API2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2)
- [`CAM::PDF`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF)
- [`CAM::PDF::PageText`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF::PageText)

From CPAN

```
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename);
my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree(1);
print CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
```

This module attempts to extract sequential text from a PDF page. This is not a robust process, as PDF text is graphically laid out in arbitrary order. This module uses a few heuristics to try to guess what text goes next to what other text, but may be fooled easily by, say, subscripts, non-horizontal text, changes in font, form fields etc.

All those disclaimers aside, it is useful for a quick dump of text from a simple PDF file.

UPDATE

Read abit more in http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/lib/CAM/PDF.pm

But there are methods like:

```
$self->getFontNames(pagenum)
```

And others which may prove helpful.

Comment: I don't need pure text but instead I need text with it's properties like font family, size or style.